# Exporting an SVG with open paths for CNC laser cutting

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, laser-cutting, laser

has anyone used jscut.org to create Gcode from an SVG for a laser cut?

jscut.org closes off my paths where there should be a line, not a polygon, is this a fault of mine, illustrator, or jscut.org's svg interpreter?

A line is not supported by jscut.org

Thank you!

[image: Closed circuit path]

---

### Update 10-1-2019

Here's the result + code, why is the path auto-closing?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12.65" height="10.44" viewBox="0 0 12.65 10.44">
  <title>test</title>
  <path d="M0,.5H9.83c2.32,0,2.32,1.74,2.32,1.74V8.6c0,1.15-1.63,1.34-1.63,1.34" style="fill: none;stroke: #000;stroke-miterlimit: 10"/>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Some code that is not the part with the problem will not help much. You could copy that line/shape in Illustrator and export just that as an SVG file

Comment: Putting only a random part of the code makes the problem worse instead of helping to find an answer. You should include the entire code.

Comment: Is it closing every path, or just some of them?

Comment: Updated, that's the issue, code posted. Does it to all paths seemingly, a number of which are lines so you don't notice the circuit, but presumably there's still a circuit (so it would double cut the single line, for example, or in the above case, it's going to cut from the end to the beginning to finish it..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

JSCUT.org seems to behaviourally close open paths - **it's not an SVG issue**.
I **changed** the path to an **expanded object** (Object -> Expand) in **Illustrator** with a stroke of 1pt and it makes a **closed** path in that same shape (a box around the line effectively doubling the path up)

It's not great for a laser to re-cut the path twice, so I'll need to experiment, but it's resolved the issue I've requested help for, thanks for prompting me to investigate further guys.

Cheers